# Any method to optimize the algorithm of Apriori for Data Mining?

Tags: apriori

I am mining some data.
I want to save time.
So any method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Using correct programing language (EX: using VB can be disastrous)
2. Formulate what information you need and code your program accordingly
3. reduce database size or prepare your database according to your need
4. SUPER COMPUTER (yes hardware does matter, joking aside you need a good computer esp for a very large dataset)
5. Improve Apriori algorithm itself by :

   •Hash-based itemset counting: A k-itemset whose corresponding hashing bucket count is below the threshold cannot be frequent.
   •Transaction reduction: A transaction that does not contain any frequent k-itemsetis useless in subsequent scans.
   •Partitioning:Any itemset that is potentially frequent in DB must be frequent in at least one of the partitions of DB.
   •Sampling: mining on a subset of given data, lower support threshold + a method to determine the completeness.
   •Dynamic itemset counting: add new candidate itemsets only when all of their subsets are estimated to be frequent.

Answer (score 3):

If you are mining data and you want to save time, you should consider using FPGrowth instead of trying to optimize Apriori.

Even if you optimize Apriori, it will not be as fast as a good implementation of FPGrowth.

Apriori is important because it is the first algorithm for frequent itemset mining and association mining. But there are some much more efficient algorithm, now.